# Setting multi byte delimiter in import csv file for excel

Tags: excel, csv, excel-2019

I am trying to read a csv file in excel. I want to make the csv file in such a way that user can open the csv file in excel without doing any effort. All the queries related to opening the file should be handle by the params passed in csv file.
I need to set the multi-byte delimiter.
If my csv file contains the data:-

```
sep=;
ColumnA;ColumnB;ColumnC
1;2;3
100;200;300
```

Then everything works fine. But if I set multi-byte delimiter, then things don't work. Like if the file have data

```
sep=#;
ColumnA#;ColumnB#;ColumnC
1#;2#;3
100#;200#;300
```

The data is not displaying in excel sheet as expected.

Comment: Rather than poking at excel, imho, it is easier to open the csv in notepad++ then do a 'find and replace' and chg all `#;` to `;`

Comment: I would be surprised if Excel can recognize that, but will follow this thread in case I am incorrect. Also, I have read that using `sep=` will disable UTF-8 encoding conveyed by the `BOM` if it is present.

Comment: @p._phidot_ I can configure separator/delimiter at first place. My main question is to use a multi byte separator/delimiter and then read that csv file using excel.(No deflection from requirement)

Comment: That is what I meant. IMHO, since there is no direct way in excel to set a multi byte delimiter in excel.. y not use another tools to chg the multi character delimiter to single character first.. then proceed as usual in excel ..